# How to do MultiClient server in java and then do the command passing between them

Tags: java, server

I have tried to do multi-client server program in java. When I was  doing it in single machine it was executing but while I was doing it in separate machine then its not executing.After creating the multi-client server two numbers will be input taken from the user and need to perform operations like (+,-,*,/,^). Help me with the proper code. And also if we take a no like 2456789345 then it wont be accept cause it will be beyond range then we need to perform FORK AND JOIN using java I need that code also.

```
for client:
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
public class client
{
private static Socket socket; 
public static void main(String args[])
{
try
{
String host = "localhost";
int port = 25000;
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
socket = new Socket(address, port);
//Send the message to the server
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
String number = "16";
String sendMessage = number + "\n";
bw.write(sendMessage);
bw.flush();
System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+sendMessage);
//Get the return message from the server
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String message = br.readLine();
System.out.println("Message received from the server : " +message);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
exception.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
//Closing the socket
try
{
socket.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
}
 for server:
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.*;
public class server
{   private static Socket socket;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
try
{
int port = 25000;
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port 25000");
while(true)
{
socket = serverSocket.accept();
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String number = br.readLine();
System.out.println("Message received from client is "+number);
String returnMessage;
try
{
int numberInIntFormat = Integer.parseInt(number);
int returnValue = numberInIntFormat*2;
returnMessage = String.valueOf(returnValue) + "\n";
}
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
//Input was not a number. Sending proper message back to client.
returnMessage = "Please send a proper number\n";
} 
//Sending the response back to the client.
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
bw.write(returnMessage);
System.out.println("Message sent to the client is "+returnMessage);
bw.flush();
}
}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
try
{
socket.close();
}
catch(Exception e){}
}
}
}
```

but i want to take two nos from user and then perform the task like (add,sub,mul,div). so i need that code.

Comment: What is your specific question, what have you tried yet, other obvious questions ?

Comment: Where is your code? What exactly is the question?

Comment: 'It's not executing' is not a problem description. Try harder.

Answer (score 0):

Client:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class multipleclient extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Runnable,  FocusListener
{
    Thread sd,r;

    Socket s;
    DataOutputStream ds;
    Scanner sc;
    String msg,msg1;
    JTextField text;
    JButton send;
    JTextArea chat;
    volatile boolean val=false;

    multipleclient()
    {
        try
        {
            s=new Socket("localhost",999);
            ds=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            sc=new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        }

        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException");
        }

        Container c=getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        text=new JTextField(30);
        text.setText("Enter your message"); 
        text.addFocusListener(this);
        send=new JButton("send");
        chat=new JTextArea(10,10);
        chat.setEditable(false);

        c.add(chat);
        c.add(text);
        c.add(send);

        send.addActionListener(this);

        sd=new Thread(this,"send");
        r=new Thread(this,"receive");
        sd.start();
        r.start();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        val=true;
    }   

    public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe)
    {
        text.setText("");
    }   

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe){}

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
        //  System.out.println("In While loop");
            if(Thread.currentThread()==sd)
            {

                try
                {
                    if(val)
                    {

                        msg=text.getText(); 
                        if(!(msg.equals(null)))
                        {
                            ds.writeBytes(msg+"\n");
                            text.setText("Enter your message");
                            val=false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("IOException");
                }   
            }

            else if(Thread.currentThread()==r)
            {

                msg1=sc.nextLine();

                chat.append(msg1+"\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        multipleclient mc1=new multipleclient();
        mc1.setSize(300,300);
        mc1.setVisible(true);
        mc1.setTitle("Client");
    }
}
```

Server:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class SingleFrameServer1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener, FocusListener, Runnable
{
    Thread r[];
    ServerSocket ss;
    Socket s[];
    Container c;
    DataOutputStream ds[];
    Scanner sc[];
    static String msg,msg1;
    static JTextField text;
    static JButton send[];
    JTextArea chat;
    volatile boolean val;
    int n;

    SingleFrameServer1() 
    {   
        n=0;    
        val=false;
        c=getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        send=new JButton[10];
        sc=new Scanner[10];
        ds=new DataOutputStream[10];
        s=new Socket[10];

        text=new JTextField(30);
        text.setText("Enter your message");
        text.addFocusListener(this);
        chat=new JTextArea(10,10);
        chat.setEditable(false);

        c.add(chat);
        c.add(text);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300,300);

        setTitle("Server");

        r=new Thread[10];

        try{
            ss=new ServerSocket(999);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IOException"+e);
        }

        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                s[n]=ss.accept();
                setVisible(true);
                ds[n]=new DataOutputStream(s[n].getOutputStream());
                sc[n]=new Scanner(s[n].getInputStream());
                c.add(send[n]=new JButton("send"+n));
                send[n].addActionListener(this);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
                (new Thread(this,"Receive"+(n++))).start();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("IOException"+e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        int i=Integer.parseInt(ae.getActionCommand().substring(4));

        msg=text.getText();
        try{
            if(!(msg.equals(null)))
            {
                ds[i].writeBytes(msg+"\n");
                text.setText("Enter your message");             
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        int i;

        while(true){    
            i=Integer.parseInt((Thread.currentThread().getName()).substring(7));
            msg1=sc[i].nextLine();
            chat.append(msg1+"\n");
        }
    }

    public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe)
    {
        text.setText("");
    }

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe){}

    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        SingleFrameServer1 ms1=new SingleFrameServer1();
    }
}
```

try this code.first run the server then run client. every time you run the client from a new cmd this will generate a new button in server frame and make communication with it.
I've made this programs and tested. it works correctly.

Comment: Thank u for this but its creating different server for different client. i need one server and multiple client

Comment: I've that also .If u want

Comment: I edited code posted above. now it won't generate new frame each time. it'll simply add a button in the server frame..upvote and accept if u wanted this solution. Always happy to help..

Comment: thanx a lot.. ok now i need to take two nos from the client... and send it to server to perfrm addition subtraction multiplication then server will send back the rrsult to the client.but while doing this FORK & JOIN need to be done because i need to show tht if the no is which was the input somethng like 2454689367 which is greater tgan the input range thwn it will be devided into two clients using fork and the result will show in server by joining them.. basically need to show that the task is breaking.